# Render SVG symbols with MapServer on Windows

Tags: symbology, mapserver, svg

I am using MapServer in a windows machine in order to build a map with data from openstreetmap and OpenSeaMap. I want to style some elements in the map and I want to use SVG symbols for doing this.

In this link http://mapserver.org/development/rfc/ms-rfc-73.html it is mentioned that the libsvg-cairo library must be installed but there is no explanation on how this is done (for windows).

Does anyone know how may I install this library in MapServer in a Windows environment?

Or does anyone know how may I style elements in MapServer by using as symbols SVG icons?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that you haven't already got it? for example the GetCapabilities response for my Windows MapServer service reports:

```
<!-- MapServer version 6.4.1 OUTPUT=GIF OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG 
OUTPUT=KML  SUPPORTS=PROJ SUPPORTS=GD SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE 
SUPPORTS=CAIRO SUPPORTS=SVG_SYMBOLS SUPPORTS=SVGCAIRO SUPPORTS=ICONV   
SUPPORTS=FRIBIDI SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WMS_CLIENT  
SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER 
SUPPORTS=SOS_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI SUPPORTS=THREADS SUPPORTS=GEOS 
INPUT=JPEG INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE -->
```

Binaries from [gisinternals](http://www.gisinternals.com/)